# What is the return type of a linq query result from two tables?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-forms-designer

I want to return a list of extracted data from two tables into a `DataGridView` with given column names.

```
public DataTable GetInfo(int id)
        {
            var stats = new List<string>();
            using MyContext db = new MyContext();

            var linqResult = (from Round in db.Rounds
                             join Hands in db.Hands on Round.RoundID equals Hands.RoundID
                             where Round.UserID == id
                             select new
                             {
                                 ID = Round.RoundID,
                                 Status = Round.Status,
                                 DatePlayed = Round.DatePlayed,
                                 Cards = Hands.PlayerCards,
                                 Score = Hands.PlayerScore
                             });

            return (DataTable)linqResult;
        }
```

The code above returns the correct values but the names of the columns are set to default in the `DataGridView`. I did some google searching and tried `ToString()` but I am not able to figure out the correct return type as `linqResult` is defined as a Generic List with anonymous types. What I want is to avoid naming all the columns manually.

Thank you!

Comment: Use object for return type unless type is really a table.  A Context is a set of Class objects.  I will post data to convert to a DataTable.

Comment: @jdweng The DataViewGrid still comes out without the column names, just as item1, item2 etc.

Comment: Check [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/list-to-datatable-converter-using-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Code below will put your data into a DataTable

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DatePlayed", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Cards", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));

            foreach (var result in linqResult)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { result.ID, result.Status, result.DatePlayed, result.Cards, result.Score });

            }
```

Comment: Same issue here, column names doesn't display in the Grid. Maybe the issue lies somewhere else..

Comment: You can make the column names with the add anything you want. The names do not have to match the Context names.   Just make sure the order in the dt.Rows.Add() are in the same order that you add the columns to the DataTable.